# Securing a website for my school project

Tags: php, sql-injection, secure-coding

I have been given a task to secure a website which will be done by my group mates, but I have no clue. Could someone give my ideas? and how I am going to protect? what code can I use to secure login page?

Comment: This is wayyy too broad."Securing" a website is not like a checklist.

Comment: You have been given this task but you don't have a clue about information security? Then it sounds like you should not accept this task. This question is too broad and can't be answered, but you can start learning from OWASP, as suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely sounds like you could get clarity on a the task.

But if that's all you have, I would start here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet

These are the 10 most common vulnerabilities for web applications. I would suggest going through each one following the instructions for checking whether they exist and steps to remediate them.